# Custom keyboard extension appearance is always dark?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

When I run my custom keyboard, it's always being styled with my dark style. If I use they keyboard in Safari for example, this code returns yellow when it should be red. If I then pull down Spotlight it still returns yellow. What am I doing wrong here?

```
override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
    self.nextKeyboardButton.backgroundColor = myColor
}

var myColor: UIColor {
    get {
        var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
        if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Light {
            return UIColor.redColor()
        } else {
            return UIColor.yellowColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Test on real device. In some condition, it's same style of System keyboard.

Comment: You declare myColor outside textDidChange , that't wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `proxy.keyboardAppearance` won't always return `.Light` even if it is the light keyboard - it may return `.Default`. To solve the problem, I changed the conditional to check for `.Dark` else return a color appropriate for the light keyboard.